# Setting up network folder repository with plain text files

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to setup a network drive as a main repo for our source that stores it as plain text?

I have this setup where there are existing plain text files on a network drive and I thought it would be useful to use Git for version control.

I've read many articles/threads on creating a network drive repo and using it and I've basically trimmed it down to the following commands:

Create bare git repo on the network drive

```
cd //server/location/repo_area
git init --bare
```

then I'd clone the bare repo that I just created into my local drive

```
cd C:/git/mylocalrepo
git clone //server/location/repo_area .
```

What happens now is that it will clone an "empty" repo and not bother downloading the existing text files.

Am I doing something wrong?

### Other things I've tried

I've tried the other way around. Copied all the text files in local drive and commited. Then clones this repo to the network drive with --bare parameter.

This seems to work where network drive does work as a main repo but when I check out the files, they seemed to be compiled into git objects rather than having plain files.
eg. objects folder had bunch of folders like 00 0a 0b 0c etc.

Is it possible to store them as plain text so I can just read it on the notepad?

Answer (score 0):

The commands you create remote repo and clone it is correct.

Why you cloned an empty repo, it's because there is no commit in the repo, so it's empty.

What you should do next is make changes, commit changes and push it to remote repo.

```
# In C:/git/mylocalrepo, add files or make changers
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

Now the changed you committed will store in the network.

---

If the files you want to push to the network repo already exist in another place, you can use below way to push it directly:

```
#Assume the files exist in //server/location/folder1
cd //server/location/folder1
git init
git remote add origin //server/location/repo_area
git add .
git commit -m 'add all files'
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Does that mean I should copy and paste all the files from the network drive (where the existing source resides) into the local drive and commit them? I would have thought I'd be doing that the other way around where I'd check in those existing files on the network drive then download it into my local drive

Comment: Yes, since your local repo is located in local drive, you should put the files in the local and then commit and push to remote repo. I will give you another way to push the files directly to remote repo in my answer.

Comment: You can also refer the second way in my answer which the files exist in the network already, and you can create a local repo there, and then push to remote.

Comment: I've tried the first method and that is working fine. However, I am not seeing the actual files that I am dealing with in the network repository. They seemed to be compiled into encoded files within the objects folder. Is there a way to store them as normal files on the network folder so I can view it with notepad?

Comment: Sorry, I've mistakenly pressed enter after the first sentence. My main problem is that they are stored as encoded files and not readable files. Is there a way around that?

Comment: That's the working mechanism for remote repo. Remote repo is bare repo which means there is no working directory, so you can't find the files in remote repo. The way to view the files store in remote repo is that clone a local copy for it, and then you can find the files in local repo.